# Turn off VSCode Typescript Errors for .JS / .JSX files & keep them for .TS / .TSX files?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, next.js, eslint

I am trying to use typescript as well as plain javascript. So some files are javascript files (.js), while others are typescript files (.ts). This works.

*However, my eslint in VSCode gives me  Typescript Errors & Warnings, even in the plain javascript files.*

Can I turn those off for the .js files, but keep them turned on whenever the file is a `.ts` / `.tsx` ?

My eslint & typescript configs are just [Vercels official typescript example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-typescript-eslint-jest).

`.eslintignore` :

```
**/node_modules/*
**/out/*
**/.next/*
```

`.eslintrc.json` :

```
{
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    // Uncomment the following lines to enable eslint-config-prettier
    // Is not enabled right now to avoid issues with the Next.js repo
    "prettier",
    "prettier/@typescript-eslint"
  ],
  "env": {
    "es6": true,
    "browser": true,
    "jest": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "settings": {
    "react": {
      "version": "detect"
    }
  },
  "rules": {
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": 0,
    "react/display-name": 0,
    "react/prop-types": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-member-accessibility": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/indent": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/member-delimiter-style": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": [
      2,
      {
        "argsIgnorePattern": "^_"
      }
    ],
    "no-console": [
      2,
      {
        "allow": ["warn", "error"]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.json` :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", ".next", "out", "**/*.js", "**/*.jsx"],
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"] 
}
```

[image]

Comment: do you see the eslint ignore file?

Comment: also look at your tsconfig

Comment: but i still want to lint my `.js` / `.jsx` files, just not through typescript. the rest of the linting config I'd like to keep for these files

Comment: Have you tried removing `"**/*.js"` from the `include` array in your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: Can you post your .eslintignore file contents too in the question?

Comment: @juliomalves Tried just now, but VSCode is still showing me typescript errors for those js files. Also tried restarting VSCode afterwards, but it's still doing it. I'll include my `tsconfig` & `ieslintignore` into the question (but they're pretty much exactly & unmodified from the repo I cloned & link to)

Comment: @hendrixchord just added those files to the question! :) thanks for having a look!!

Comment: Did you find the answer? I've been looking for this solution for a long time.

Comment: @Chi this worked for me 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52938648/ignore-js-and-jsx-files-with-tsconfig-json

Answer (score -3):

In your `.eslintignore` file add this line

`**/*.js`

By which eslint will not lint any *.js files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't want to not lint all my `.js` files. There are certain checks my linter does, that I want to use. I just don't want to apply typescript to those files.