# Property 'innerText' does not exist on type 'Element'.ts (2339)

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm using javaScript and I wrote a function but somehow I'm getting these error messages and I really can't figure out why. In the beginning, I could not even make a js file because every time I wrote script.js it just transformed into script.ts. Nevertheless, somehow I manage to make it script.js and now I'm totally confused. I saw on some posts here that these are the type of errors you get in TypeScript but I'm using JavaScript. this is the code :

```js
function loadSong(song){

    title.innerText = song. 
    audio.src = `music/${song}.mp3`
    cover.src = `img/${song}.jpg`
}
```

I got errors on `innerText` and `src`

So please help.

Comment: to stop type-checking `.js` files, you'd have to explicitly exclude them in your `tsconfig.json`. [link to possible similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52938648/ignore-js-and-jsx-files-with-tsconfig-json)

Comment: and how do I do that?  

Comment: never mind found it did it haha sorry but thank you for the help 

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you.

Use the type `HTMLElement` instead of `Element`. `HTMLElement` inherits from `Element`.
Correct (type safe) way can be:

```js
if (element instanceof HTMLElement) {
  element.innerText=song. 
}
```